# Writing from lines into columns based on third column

Tags: awk, sed

I have files that look like this -- already sorted by year (inside years sorted by id, which appears to be equivalent to strict sorting by id, but this may not always apply).

```
ID,COU,YEA, VOT 
1,USA,2000,1
2,USA,2000,0
3,USA,2001,1
4,USA,2003,2
5,USA,2003,0
```

I would like to rewrite them like this (ids for year N after 1999 in column 2N-1, corresponding votes in column 2N):

```
2000 IDS, VOTE, 2001 IDS, VOTE, 2002 IDS, VOTE, 2003 IDS, VOTE
1,1,3,1, , ,4,2
2,0, , , , ,5,0
```

I don't know how to do it. My basic thinking with `awk` was:

- if $3 == 2000, { print $1, $4 }
- if $3 == 2001, { print " "," ", $1, $4 } etc

But there are two problems:

1. this way the columns for years other than 2000 would start with a lot of empty lines
2. I have found no intelligent way to generalise the print command, so I would have to write 20 if-statements

The only working idea I have is, to create 20 unneeded files and glue them with `paste` which I have never used, but which seems suitable, according to `man` on my system.

Comment: Could you please do let us know if your Input_file is always sorted by year's increasing order?

Comment: Yes, it is! I have applied sort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use multidimensional arrays

```
BEGIN {FS = ","}
NR == 2 {minYear = maxYear = $3}
NR > 1 {
    year=$3
    count[year]++
    id[year, count[year]] = $1
    vote[year, count[year]] = $4

    if (year < minYear) minYear = year
    if (year > maxYear) maxYear = year
    if (count[year] > maxCount) maxCount = count[year]
}
END {
    sep = ""
    for (y=minYear; y<=maxYear; y++) {
        printf "%s%d ID,VOTE", sep, y
        sep = ","
    }
    print ""
    for (i=1; i<=maxCount; i++) {
        sep = ""
        for (y=minYear; y<=maxYear; y++) {
            printf "%s%s,%s", sep, id[y, i], vote[y, i]
            sep = ","
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Then,

```sh
$ awk -f transpose.awk input_file
2000 ID,VOTE,2001 ID,VOTE,2002 ID,VOTE,2003 ID,VOTE
1,1,3,1,,,4,2
2,0,,,,,5,0
```

---

If you *really* want hte spaces in the output, change the last `printf` to

```
            printf "%s%s,%s", sep, 
                ((y, i) in id   ? id[y, i]   : " "),
                ((y, i) in vote ? vote[y, i] : " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is functionally the same as @Glenn's and no better than it in any way so his should remain the accepted answer but I came up with it before looking at his and thought it might be useful to post it anyway to show some small alternatives in style and implementation details:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 { next }
{
    id    = $1
    year  = $3
    votes = $4

    if ( ++numYears == 1 ) {
        begYear = year
    }
    endYear = year

    yearIds[year,++numIds[year]] = id
    yearVotes[year,numIds[year]] = votes
    maxIds = (numIds[year] > maxIds ? numIds[year] : maxIds)
}
END {
    for (year=begYear; year<=endYear; year++) {
        printf "%s IDS%sVOTE%s", year, OFS, (year<endYear ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (idNr=1; idNr<=maxIds; idNr++) {
        for (year=begYear; year<=endYear; year++) {
            id = votes = " "
            if ( (year,idNr) in yearIds ) {
                id = yearIds[year,idNr]
                votes = yearVotes[year,idNr]
            }
            printf "%s%s%s%s", id, OFS, votes, (year<endYear ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2000 IDS,VOTE,2001 IDS,VOTE,2002 IDS,VOTE,2003 IDS,VOTE
1,1,3,1, , ,4,2
2,0, , , , ,5,0
```

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah, it's useful if you know in advance where the loop ends, not useable with `for (i in arr) ...` though whereas you can use the `sep="";for ...sep=OFS` trick (or the equivalent`cnt=0;for ... (cnt++ ? OFS : "")` with either one so I'm sometimes in 2 minds if I should use `? OFS : ORS` or not even when I can given it's not universally applicable. At the end of the day I just don't care enough to make a final decision :-).

Answer (score 2):

With respect and permission of [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) I am taking his suggested code the only thing I am trying to add here is get maximum and minimum year in `awk`'s variable itself and NOT calculating it inside main block of `awk` program, since OP confirmed that Input_file is sorted by year. Answers by Glenn and Ed sir are awesome, just thought to add a variant here.

BTW we could use `awk` in stead of using `tail` and `head`s in variables too here :)

```
awk -v max=$(tail -1 Input_file | cut -d, -f3) -v min=$(head -2 Input_file | tail -1 | cut -d, -f3) '
BEGIN { FS = "," }
NR > 1 {
    year=$3
    count[year]++
    id[year, count[year]] = $1
    vote[year, count[year]] = $4
    if (count[year] > maxCount) maxCount = count[year]
}
END {
    sep = ""
    for (y=min; y<=max; y++) {
        printf "%s%d ID,VOTE", sep, y
        sep = ","
    }
    print ""
    for (i=1; i<=maxCount; i++) {
        sep = ""
        for (y=min; y<=max; y++) {
            printf "%s%s,%s", sep, id[y, i], vote[y, i]
            sep = ","
        }
        print ""
    }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: head and tail are efficient, but you are now processing the input file 3 times.

Comment: @glennjackman, yeah but variables are getting created before reading main program and each line calculations for finding max, min years is not happening so may be its adjusted there? If you think so sir. Tried this for fun :)

Comment: One thing to consider is that you now require the input to be in a file, you couldn't run it on input coming through a pipe from a stream since it has to open the input 3 times.